# Can I use Alea.cuBase / Alea GPU with CUDA 8.0?

Tags: aleagpu

I just tried to run Alea TK samples on machine with GTX 1070, and:

- CUDA 7.5 installs, but doesn't seem to work there. NVidia says CUDA 8.0RC should be used with this GPU: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/949823/cuda-setup-and-installation/when-the-cuda-toolkit-will-support-gtx1070-graphics-card-/
- CUDA 8.0 also successfully installs there, but it seems all the bindings in Alea.cuBase are to CUDA 7.5 -- i.e. basically, all samples fail on attempt to load CUDA 7.5's "cu*64_75.dll" libraries, though 8.0 version includes similar ones with "_80" suffix.
- Same samples run on machines with less recent GPUs (and thus CUDA 7.5) without any issues.

Is there any way to address this, or I should wait for an updated version of Alea.cuBase?

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 1070 has a new GPU of Pascal architecture in it. Starting with Alea GPU V3 beta 17 we support also Pascal. Give it a try. Cuda 8 should also work. But you have to use the new Alea GPU version 3 beta release. The old Alea GPU v 2.2 is not capable to compile for Pascal.

Comment: Sorry Daniel i don't believe it does work... https://github.com/quantalea/AleaGPUTutorial/issues/11

Comment: The issue is resolved with Alea GPU 3.0.1 release or later.